# Tiny ORM issue in PHP

Tags: php, static

I'm trying to build a tiny ORM class that models will extend so, if for example I call the method `User::find(1)` it will give me the 'User' model that haves the `id` of `1` in the database.

This is my attempt:

```
class ORM
{
    private static $table, $database;

    function __construct() {
        self::getConnection();
    }

    private static function getConnection (){
        require_once('Database.php');
        error_log('Getting connection');
        self::$database = Database::getConnection(DB_PROVIDER, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DB);
    }

    public static function find($id) {
        $obj = null;
        self::getConnection();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id = ?";
        $results = self::$database->execute($query,null,array(self::$table,$id));
        print_r();
        if ($results){
            $obj = new self($results);
        }
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

And then, the class `User` for example.

```
include('ORM.php');
include('../../config.php');

class User extends ORM
{
    public $id, $name;
    private static $table = 'user';

    public function __construct($data){
        parent::__construct();
        if ($data && sizeof($data)) { $this->populateFromRow($data); }
    }

    public function populateFromRow($data){
        $this->id = isset($data['id']) ? intval($data['id']) : null;
        $this->name = isset($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : null;
    }
}

print_r(User::find(1));
```

I put those includes and that print_r just for testing, it won't remain there after.

The issue is that it seems that the method `find` doesn't read the `$table` from the class and it doesn't read nothing. So the query isn't executed fine and returns nothing but an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The other solution is to not use static methods and members. That has the benefit that you can actually test your code and it is more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `self` in your code to `static`. Note that it will only work in php >= 5.3. [Read more about late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that but this error arises `Cannot access private property User::$table in /inc/class/ORM.php on line 26` it doesn't have sense to me to make the property public although there shouldn't be no issues.

Comment: it should be `protected` to be available for inheriting classes